# reduce $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}-k\Delta v=0$ to $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}-\Delta v=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to reduce $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}-k\Delta v=0$$ to $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}-\Delta v=0$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** make a change of variables $$
v(x,t) = w\left(\frac xL, t\right)
$$

With such a definition,
$$
\Delta u(x,t) = \sum_i \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}\left[
 w\left(\frac xL, t\right)
\right]
= \frac 1{L^2}  \sum_i \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}
 w\left(\frac xL, t\right) = \frac 1{L^2}\Delta w\left(\frac xL, t\right)
$$

---

Alternative:

the equation is also equivalent to
$$
\frac 1k\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}-\Delta v=0
$$

Hence it could be interesting to define
$$
v(x,t) = w(x,kt)
$$

Comment: ...or a new time-coordinate, which is a bit simpler.

Comment: @Winther indeed, I added an alternative verson. thanks!